# "before each" hook for "Initializes the NFT Correctly.": TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'JsonRpcProvider')

Tags: web3js, nft

Getting this error while basicNft test
the error
[image]

the test

```js
// We are going to skip a bit on these tests...

const { assert } = require("chai")
const { network, deployments, ethers } = require("hardhat")
const { developmentChains } = require("../../helper-hardhat-config")

//writing the test code from here..

!developmentChains.includes(network.name)
    ? describe.skip
    : describe("Basic NFT Unit Tests", function () {
          let basicNft, deployer

          beforeEach(async () => {
              accounts = await ethers.getSigners()
              deployer = accounts[0]
              await deployments.fixture(["basicnft"])
              basicNft = await ethers.getContract("BasicNft")
          })
        
        describe("Constructor", () => {
            it("Initializes the NFT Correctly.", async () => {
                const name = await basicNft.name()
                const symbol = await basicNft.symbol()
                const tokenCounter=await basicNft.getTokenCounter()
                assert.equal(name, "DOGIE")
                assert.equal(symbol, "DOG")
                assert.equal(tokenCounter.toString(),"0")
            })
        })
//test02
        describe("Mint NFT", () => {
          beforeEach(async () => {
              const txResponse = await basicNft.mintNft()
              await txResponse.wait(1)
          })
          it("Allows users to mint an NFT, and updates appropriately", async function () {
              const tokenURI = await basicNft.tokenURI(0)
              const tokenCounter = await basicNft.getTokenCounter()

              assert.equal(tokenCounter.toString(), "1")
              assert.equal(tokenURI, await basicNft.TOKEN_URI())
          })
          it("Show the correct balance and owner of an NFT", async function () {
              const deployerAddress = deployer.address;
              const deployerBalance = await basicNft.balanceOf(deployerAddress)
              const owner = await basicNft.ownerOf("0")

              assert.equal(deployerBalance.toString(), "1")
              assert.equal(owner, deployerAddress)
          })
        })
    })
```

the deploy-basicNft.js

```js
const {network} = require("hardhat")
const {developmentChains} = require("../helper-hardhat-config")
const {verify} = require("../utils/verify")

module.exports = async function({getNamedAccounts, deployments}){
    const {deploy, log} = deployments;
    const {deployer} = await getNamedAccounts();

    log("....................")
    const args = []
    const basicNft = await deploy("BasicNft",{
        from: deployer,
        args: args,
        log: true,
        waitConfirmations: network.config.blockConfirmations || 1,
    })
    
    if(!developmentChains.includes(network.name) && process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY){
        log("verifying...")
        await verify(basicNft.address, args)   
    }
    log("..............................")
}
```

the BasicNft.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: SEE LICENSE IN LICENSE
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

contract BasicNft is ERC721{
     string public constant TOKEN_URI =
        "ipfs://bafybeig37ioir76s7mg5oobetncojcm3c3hxasyd4rvid4jqhy4gkaheg4/?filename=0-PUG.json";
    uint256 private s_tokenCounter;
    constructor() ERC721("DOGIE", "DOG") {
        s_tokenCounter = 0;
    }
    
    function mintNft() public returns(uint256){
        _safeMint(msg.sender, s_tokenCounter);
        s_tokenCounter = s_tokenCounter +1;
        return s_tokenCounter;
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 /*tokenId*/) public view override returns(string memory){
        //require(_exits(tokenId))
        return TOKEN_URI;
    }

    function getTokenCounter() public view returns(uint256){
        return s_tokenCounter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The solution was downgrading ethers to 5.7.2 from 6.0.8. So, go to package.json and change into: "ethers": "^5.7.2".

Then you need to apply the changes through yarn add --dev hardhat.

This worked for me.